# Are Facebook POST's timezone aware?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Aloha

I've been struggling to find supporting documentation, forum posts (that are clear) and within the SDK (Graph API) if "Facebook POSTS" are timezone aware?

That is, if on my personal/business account I schedule a POST for 7:00 AM SAST (South African Standard Time). Will someone who is in London, then see my POST at 7:00 AM (their time) or at the time of my post (1 hour behind) 6:00 AM?

Thank you

Comment: All people will see it at the same “global” time.

Comment: @CBroe can you clarify? Will each person see my post at 7:00AM, at 7:00AM for them?

Comment: No, the other way around. The will all see it at the same point in time - what local “name” that point in time might have in different places of the world, does not matter here.